# Cocos2d-x Project with Xcode 4.3 and Visual Studio 2010 GIT (BitBucket)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, xcode4.3, bitbucket, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-x is a way to create applications for iOS and Android 'simultaneously' because it uses C++ (Cocos2d uses Objective-C).

The problem is this:

We have a project in Visual Studio 2010 of Cocos2d-x and was uploaded to a repository "A" in BitBucket with Git Control Provider. You can pull/push normally from/to BitBucket. Then we have a Mac OS X Lion with Xcode 4.3 (git comes native) and is configured to point to the repository "A". When we try to pull that repository, this error appears:

-> "[ProjectName]/v1" is not a valid remote branch to pull from.

I don't know if this problem is because of the compatibility between projects (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has it's own files and Xcode has it's own files). If this is the case... Is there a possibility to make the git compatible?

In case of being compatible... How can we create a project in Xcode 4.3 from a git in bitBucket? We can't seem to find the option when a project is created...

Cheers!

Comment: I don't have the answer but you'll definitely have to look for configuration errors in Xcode or Mac OS respectively. Xcode works with any git project, it doesn't matter which hosting site (bitbucket, github, etc) you're using. Check if you can push/pull the git repository from the command line. If not, then git is not setup properly on the system. Follow the git instructions for Mac OS. Another thing you should try is to install the same git version on all machines.